# [UINavigationController selectedIndex]: unrecognized selector sent to instance of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

While navigating from one screen to another screen(Instance/SubScreen of TabBarController), app is getting crashed and throwing error.

> Thread 1: "-[UINavigationController selectedIndex]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x105870800"

```
 UINavigationController *nav_1 = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    
 UITabBarController *tab = (TabbarController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
 NSInteger sel_idx =  tab.selectedIndex; //App Crashing here with error:- Thread 1: "-[UINavigationController selectedIndex]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x105870800"
 UINavigationController *nav = [tab.viewControllers objectAtIndex:sel_idx];
```

- Before it's working fine when screen redirecting with below code, but facing error of `Multiple Navigation Stack`, which caused **unwanted crashes** and **app freezing issue**

```
 if ((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "isUserSignIn") as? Bool) == true)
 {
     NSLog("if called tabBarController")
     self.window?.rootViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController")
 } 
 else
 {
    self.window?.rootViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileNavController")                                                          
 }
```

- Now I've changed code as below, bcz I'm facing issue of `Multiple Navigation Stack`. So after changing to below code `Multiple Navigation Stack` issue has been resolved but facing mentioned **error**

```
if ((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "isUserSignIn") as? Bool) == true)
{
   NSLog("if called tabBarController")
   let tabBar = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController")
   nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabBar)
   self.window?.rootViewController = nav
} 
else
{
               
  NSLog("else called LoginViewController")                    
  let login = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
  nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: login)
  self.window?.rootViewController = nav
                                       
}
```

- Crashing with **error**

[image: error image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the tab after you changed the root to a navigation you need

```
 UINavigationController *nav_1 = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
 UITabBarController *tab = [nav_1.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]
```